Error in petalinux-build sdk when using mbedtls
I am trying to generate the petalinux sdk for my project using petalinux-build --sdk It works fine, until I add TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK = "mbedtls" in my petalinuxbsp.conf file, at which point I get this error :
file /usr/bin/.debug/hello conflicts between attempted installs of mbedtls-dbg-2.28.2-r0.1.cortexa72_cortexa53 and lmbench-dbg-3.0+a9-r2.0.cortexa72_cortexa53

As far as I can tell the error message is telling me that mbedtls-dbg and lmbench-dbg both export the /usr/bin/.debug/hello file. lmbench is a dependency of mbedtls, so I can't remove it.
I tried to add a mbedtls_%.bbappend file with FILES:${PN}-dbg = "" inside, but it did not fix it.
Any help appreciated, thanks.
